# How to really works JSF: xhtmls, controllers, servelet and HTTP actions?

Tags: http, jsf, primefaces, controller, xhtml

### I understand that:

a) On the server side I have: xhtmls (views), controllers (managed beans) and servelet (general manager)

b) On the client side I have: page requests actions via HTTP

### Question:

How is the process since a request for a page is done until finally the browser receives the HTML and displays it?

### Example:

1-Client: get request (HTML page)

2-Server: redirects the request to servelet

3- ...

*Try to build a sequence diagram but without success.*

Comment: This is independent of any technology (TCP / IP model or Open Systems Interconnection (OSI) model in networking). In order to cover that in details, one has to write a book or blog for that.

Comment: This question is waaay too broad. Indeed just get a book on the subject. The abovelinked duplicate is your starting point. Then continue here http://stackoverflow.com/q/3541077. Then continue here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info (pay careful attention to all links therein).